# Is there an inverse OR function?

Tags: microsoft-excel

The `OR` function returns TRUE if any of the arguments are true.

Is there a function that returns FALSE if any of the arguments are false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Programming languages and rulebased languages often have operators to see if a condition is met and if so, return true.

Here is a list of what known operators are and how they work.

- OR: Gives true if eiter or both conditions are true, and returns false if both are false.
- AND: Gives true if all conditions are true and none are false.
- XOR: Gives true if exactly one condition is true, and the rest is false.
- NOT: Gives the reverse of what goes in. True becomes False, and visa versa.

You are asking for the AND clause, and Excel supports it. `=AND(value1, value2, value3)`  will result true if all these values are true or false if any of them (or all) are false.

Comment: I was thinking in the line that "with AND, all the answers has to be the same". Which is clearly the answer i were looking for. Embarrassing.

Comment: The description of many of these outputs are inaccurage.  A NOT gate for instance simply inverses the input.  If the input is TRUE then its FALSE, it its FALSE, then its TRUE.

Comment: Ah, I was sleeping a bit there. Corrected it. Thanks for the heads up. The info now is actually correct.

Answer (score 2):

**`Inverse OR`** is not the correct name for what you're asking!!

What you're looking for is **`AND`** function which returns **FALSE**  if any of the arguments are **FALSE**. To implement this, you can use this: **`=AND(value1, value2, value3)`**

Whereas **`Inverse OR`** is actually **`NOR`** function which returns **FALSE** if any of the arguments are **TRUE**. In other words, it's the combination of **`OR`** and **`NOT`** and therefore it can be implemented as: **`=NOT(OR(value1, value2, value3))`**

Comment: This answer is not actually correct w/rerd to inverse or.  The inverse of OR actually iS NOR.  When you right out a logic equation that includes (AND,NAND,OR,NOR, and NOT) OR is written as OR (with a bar over it).  The bar over any of those is considered to be the inverse.  [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_logic) is a Wikipedia article on logic.  "A NOR gate is logically an inverted OR gate. By itself has the following truth table:"  [Inverse](https://www.bing.com/search?q=inverse&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN) as a Noun means "something that is the opposite or reverse of something else:"

Comment: [NOR](http://i.stack.imgur.com/72v26.png)

Comment: and how does it differ from what I answered?

Comment: "Inverse OR is not the correct name for what you're asking!!" - While its called NOT OR (NOR), the output literally is the inverse, of an OR gate.  So "inverse or" is a correct description.  While they might have been actually looking for the output that matches an AND gate, thats not material, to the incorrect statement you made.

Comment: As you stated  " Inverse as a Noun means "something that is the opposite or reverse of something else". Exactly, Inverse OR is the opposite or reverse of OR. Exactly what I stated in my answer. Also you  said," "inverse or " is a correct description". I nowhere negate this statement in my answer.  I, rather, said that it was not what the OP was asking (as the OP is clearly asking about AND gate).

Comment: Alright;  I suppose my confusion is with the very first statement.  The way you have written it makes it sound that "Inverse OR" isn't the proper name for a NOR gate.

Answer (score -3):

The Excel function that does what you need is `AND`.

Usage:

`AND(logical 1, logical 2, logical...)`

Examples:

`=AND(1<2, 2<3)` will return `TRUE`.
`=AND(1<2, 3<2)` will return `FALSE`.

[Logical functions (reference)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Logical-functions-reference-e093c192-278b-43f6-8c3a-b6ce299931f5)

Comment: Voted down for how this was written, even though it is technically correct.

Comment: well, little more research before asking would be nice, but i thought why not give him the answer anyway

Comment: of course.. that is how `AND` works. I don't know what i was thinking.

Comment: now i even looked it up .. if you don't like my answer, write your own one or improve it .. thx

Comment: Howdy! Essentially you just posted a link, and link-only answers are a no-no here on SU.  Answers should contain all applicable information to answer the question.  If the link goes dark, your answer become useless.

Comment: This answer did not deserve this bad response!  What he answered is technically correct and answers what the OP demanded for. The mentioned link is an extra explanation. But still instead of posting the link, he should've written the most necessary information in his answer. And those who voted -1, they should have, instead, asked him to improve his answer!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama - We shouldn't have to ask somebody to improve an answer.  If user614108 had read the help center, they wouldn't have even submitted, an answer that only contains a link.  The author can still improve the anwer, and I have no doubt, every user who downvoted would reverse their vote (including me).  I ask people to improve an answer, but I also issue a vote, We are encourage by SE community managers that we should use our ability to vote on questions an answers.

Comment: @user614108 - We are encourage to provide feedback on answers when we issue a vote.  As a reviewer, submitting my own answer to this question, and providing feedback to this answer are unrealated actions.